# react-router-hash-link doesn't work if coming from a different route

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I am using `react-router-hash-link` to go to a different section within the same route:

```
import { HashLink as Link } from "react-router-hash-link";
```

In the render:

```
render() {
     <Link smooth to="#header2">
        Scroll to header 2 section
     </Link>
     <h2 id="header2"></h2>
}
```

This works. However, if I'm coming from a different route and link to another route with the hash, it doesn't scroll to the section.

e.g. Now I'm in `/routeone`

```
render() {
   <Link smooth to="/routetwo#header2">
      Go to Route Two, header 2 section
   </Link>
}
```

I've imported `HashLink` also in `/routeone` in this example.

Anything missing?

Comment: Have you polyfilled your app as mentioned in docs for react-router-hash-link ? ref : https://github.com/iamdustan/smoothscroll

Comment: I removed the 'smooth' just to test, it seems to scroll down but the scroll position is totally off.. (if same page, the scroll position is ok). @Fawaz

Comment: maybe you can add a workaround, to move to a specific hash on componentDidMount. I had a similar issue while dealing with sticky bar so had to do this.

Comment: The issue remains. It is probably a bug in the package.

Answer (score 0):

So along the lines of having to keep an `<a id="header2">` in the above answer, I added the same to a `<span>` which also worked. I then realized, in my case, that I was adding the id to my custom component which wasn't passing an id prop. Once I went added a id prop to my component HashLink began to work properly.

Answer (score -2):

instead of `<h2 id="header2"></h2>` if you keep 
`<a id="header2"></a>` it works.